# QSettings persistence constantly writing to config file on initial startup

Tags: qt

So I have a qt app running on Linux. When the app is initially launched, QSettings is constantly writing to the settings.conf file even though no changes were made to QSettings. Once a user changes any setting, it stops writing and acts like normal and only writes during changes. Our hardware does not have a power button and so never shuts off and is constantly plugged in so having QSettings constantly writing to the .conf file on start up is a problem.

I looked for timers to make sure no timer was prompting to write and there are none. Tried settings.sync(). I even set a throwaway value on start up, since after changing a value in the app after initial launch it stops writing, but that didn't work. All settings persistence is written this way and after I comment out the **settings.setValue** at the bottom of the code, the .conf write process works as supposed to. I have no idea why it is writing when values are set from a power button click. Thoughts?

Here is the code and flow:

```
void MainWindow::onNavBarButtonClicked(int buttonClickedIdAsInt)
{
//..... 
case NavBarButton::POWER:
        activeScreenContainer->setCurrentWidget(userScreen);
        activeScreenContainer ->raise();
        navBarFrame->raise();
        navBarActiveContainerSeparator->hide();
        logoUserScreen->show();
        logoUserScreen->raise();
        if(orientationSelected == appPersistence::PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION_VALUE) {
            timeAndUserFrame->hide();
        }

        emit userLoggedOut(); 
}
```

to

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::userLoggedOut, musicScreenModel,
&MusicScreenModel::onUserLoggedOut);
```

to

```
void MusicScreenModel::onUserLoggedOut()
{
    emit userLoggedOutTreble(currentTrebleValue);
}
```

to

```
connect(musicScreenModel, &MusicScreenModel::userLoggedOutTreble,
settingsScreenModel, &SettingsScreenModel::onUserLoggedOutTreble);
```

to

```
void SettingsScreenModel::onUserLoggedOutTreble(int trebleToStore)
{
    settings.setValue(appPersistence::MUSIC_TREBLE_KEY + loggedInUser,
    trebleToStore);
}
```

And main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("Organization");
    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("AppName");
    QSettings::setPath(QSettings::Format::NativeFormat,QSettings::Scope::UserScope, "/opt/");

QSettings settings;

int fontFamilyId = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf");
settings.setValue(fontStyle::QUICKSAND_BOLD_FAMILY_ID, fontFamilyId);

if(!settings.value(appPersistence::ORIENTATION_SELECTED_KEY).isValid()) {
    settings.setValue(appPersistence::ORIENTATION_SELECTED_KEY, appPersistence::LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION_VALUE);
}

if(true) {
    DevOnlyFunctions::seedRng();
}

testBuild::setIsTestBuild(false);

MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I would think that QSettings would only perform writes when necessary.  Are there no other places that you are calling settings.setValue()?

Comment: All instances of settings.setValue are in the same class so I would assume no.

Comment: Are you certain that it is writing and not re-reading the file?  I'm looking at the QSettings source right now https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp.html to try to come up with some idea of what would cause that.

Comment: All instances of settings.setValue are either in main or the a settings class that is created. The weird thing is not all instances of settings.setValue are writing to the .conf file but the code is the same. I have been trying to find differences. Will keep posted.

Comment: Without looking too deeply into it, I am wondering if two instances of QSettings are detecting a change (possibly erroneously) and re-reading the file, and maybe even deciding that it requires update after doing this, and triggering another rewrite.  It's little more than a guess, but I might try moving all QSettings stuff to some static members of one class.

Comment: It is definitely being written. In CLI I checked the file with 'ls -l' and the date and time is updated while the app is running in start screen.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what the was going wrong. We have a timer that shows whether certain Can Bus devices are present. If they are not present we hide the icons and log out the user directly through calling the onUserLoggedOut() method and not through a connect statement. I was constantly searching for a timer and connect statement and not a direct method call nested within a switch that uses a timer.

Comment: I feel like this could be informative for others potentially running into the same issue, but I'm not entirely clear from your description exactly what the problem was. (I'm particularly confused by "and log out the user directly through calling the onUserLoggedOut() method and not through a connect statement" — did you mean an `emit` statement, to signal the `onUserLoggedOut` slot?) Can you update this answer with (at least) the _wrong_ code that was causing the problem, since it turned out there was nothing wrong with any of the code in your original question? Thx.

Comment: Ah, I think now I've got it. You were trying to find someplace in the code where a QTimer was connected to one of the slots that updates the QSettings (a `connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onUserLoggedOut()));` or `connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onUserLoggedOutTreble()));`), but because the `onUserLoggedOut` slot was being called directly there was no such statement to find.